# wrong html template rendered by django view on jquery ajax get call

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, templates

My `django` app's `index.html` page uses jquery fullcalendar , populated by a django view called `index()` which uses `simplejson` to dump an array containing events for all days of current month.The method renders the `index.html` template.

I am making an `ajax get` call on click of the calendar's `prev button` which invokes another django view `prev_month()`.This method calculates the events array for the previous month and dumps it and finally renders a different template `'prev_month.html'`

```
def prev_month(request,year,month):
    ....
    prev_events=[]
    #populates array by making db calls
    return render_to_response('prev_month.html',{'prev_events':prev_events})
```

prev_month.html

```
...
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
       events: {{prev_events|safe}}
    });
        $('.fc-button-prev').click(function(){
          var d=$('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate');
          var month=d.getMonth()+1;
          var year=d.getFullYear();
          $.ajax({url:'/myapp/prev_month/'+year+'/'+month,type:"GET",
  success:function(){
                    alert('prev_month.html::success');
},
});
});
</script>
```

The template `index.html` is similar to the one above ,except that the success alert displays `'index.html::success'`.It also populates the calendar using `current_events` as passed by django view named `index()`.

The django view is

```
def index(request):
   ...
   #creates events array and jsondump
   return render_to_response('index.html',{'current_events':events_array})
```

When I go to the index page,the calendar shows all events of current month .When the prev button is clicked,the django view prev_month() is executed .But for some reason,the template rendered is the `index.html` instead of `prev_month.html`  .This is evident from success alert which shows   `index.html::success`

instead of  `prev_month.html::success`

Because of this,the events for previous month are not displayed..

Can someone help me figure out why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response from your AJAX call is not used.

You have to change your `$.ajax()` call so that the success function actually binds data (i.e. the response from the Django server); we use `$.get()` in the example to make it easier to read:

```
$.get('/myapp/prev_month/'+year+'/'+month, function(data) {
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({events: data});
});
```

See the documentation for jQuery.get over at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

This should use your `fullCalendar()` method and give it the received `data` as new value for `events`.

Have a look at the JavaScript error console to see if the format of `data` causes problems; if so, you will have to return the results as JSON inside `prev_month()`.

Comment: prev_month() inside Django does render prev_month.html; the problem is that you do not update your local page template (which was index.html) after having started the AJAX request.

Comment: Can you post the exact HTML output for your index page, including the JavaScript you are using there? That will be helpful for solving the problem :)

Comment: What is the output of prev_month() when you call it directly? HTML? JSON? Can you extend prev_month() to print prev_events to STDOUT...

Comment: when i call `/myapp/prev_month/2012/3/`  directly, I get this output.  http://pastebin.com/SUQcDGHe   This populates the entries for march ,but the webpage still shows month of April.If I click prev button now,month of march shows all events. This does not occur when I only click the prev button

Comment: prev_month view prints this to stdout  It shows all events of march  as given in the call  `/myapp/prev_month/2012/3/`  ..http://pastebin.com/esPKUM56

Comment: I'll have a look later tonight and get back to you soon